# Updating Force Layouts in D3v4

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

I am working on a force layout in D3v4 which needs to update its nodes over time. I've followed [Adding new nodes to Force-directed layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539294/adding-new-nodes-to-force-directed-layout) (D3v2) and mbostock's [block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) (D3v3), but I'm not quite sure how to achieve the same affect in D3v4. Here's what I've got so far:

http://bl.ocks.org/danielcompton/2189f9571e306f3084e5c2a913002eaf

**The problem that I'm seeing is that when I add the same data to the force layout a second time, it resets the nodes positions, and also seems to reset them with less alpha, so they don't fully expand until they are clicked.** Do I need to set the alpha as well when I'm updating the nodes and links?

I've seen [D3 v4: Update force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623530/d3-v4-update-force-layout) and this is a different (but related) question.

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this in D3 v4?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simulation is starting off with a low alpha value the way you handle it. If I just reset the alpha value with `.alpha(1)` inside the `handleGraph` it does the trick on my side:

```
simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked)
  .alpha(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

after you added the data , you can use`simulation.alpha(1).restart()` to restart simulation layout.